# PostgresQL: how to start up the database server and create a database

Tags: postgresql-9.2

When I try to run a server:

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets postgres@ubuntu:~$
```

Then I change user to myself:

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ su - michael

michael@ubuntu:~$  sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      959/postgres
```

Well, postgres seems to be listening to the port and this seems to be the problem.

Let us change pack to postgres and try to kill this process:

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ kill `cat /usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid`
```

The reaction is:

```
cat: /usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Could you recommend me how to proceed?

Answer (score 15):

First, get the running Postgres pid:

```
ps -ef | grep postmaster | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

Then kill it

```
kill <the_pid_you_just_got>
```

But unless you are trying to do something very special with Postgres (multiple instances...) you **should** stop it using **sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop** (or sudo /etc/init.d/postgres stop)  AND start it using **sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start**

Postgres runs as a **service**, and so it has a service control file/script which is in charge of correctly starting and stopping it. These control files used to be located inside /etc/init.d, but I must admit it has become a bit messy these days, with the growing number of services management systems (init, upstart, systemd...)

Comment: Well, I tried ps -ef | grep postmaster | awk '{print $1}'. Under the user michael it showed michael. Well, I stopped Postgres as you suggested. Now there is nothing to listen to the port. I could not catch your remark about start. So, I deleted the data directory. Then I started from /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data. The reaction was: creating directory /usr/local/pgsql/data ... initdb: could not create directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data": Permission denied. Earlier I created data directory manually through sudo. Now: /usr/local$ ls -l results in

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct  5 17:25 pgsql. Maybe I should just start everything from the very beginning and use another directory rather than /usr/local?

Comment: If you created 'data' yourself with sudo, it belongs to 'root', not to you. You can change that by taking ownership of this folder :  sudo chown michael. /usr/local/pgsql/data   , but Are you sure you want to run, create and manage your databases under the michael account?

Comment: Well, no, I'm too green to derive from the manual. I would like just to create my first database. I already deleted data directory and would like initdb to create it again. But it somehow couldn't do that because of permission privileges.

Comment: When I ran this command, I got 502 . so I then did the command `kill 502` but then got the error `-bash: kill: (502) - No such process`

Comment: I get a different ps id everytime i run the fist command

Comment: The first command prints 2 pids: postmaster pid itself and the running `grep postmaster` pid because it contains `postmaster` in arguments...

Comment: The suggested line is wrong and will show the grep process itself. A correct version is `ps -ef | grep postmaster | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`. If this is blank, there's nothing running called postmaster.